# NSMutableAttributedString and Adding a Link to text

Tags: ios4, osx-snow-leopard, nsattributedstring

I have a NSMutableAttributedString, Now I want to add Link to some portion of the text. how can i add a link to the text so that when the user touches the text i can fire some actions. I'm working in iOS 4.2

Thanks in Advance.
Shinto

Answer (score 0):

I did a library a few months back that dealt with that exact use case. However, I had to re-use it last week and found out that CMTextLabel isn't very user-friendly.

https://github.com/pothibo/CMFramework/tree/master/CMKit/RichText

You could have a look at it. If you decide to use it and refactor some of it to make it easier to use, send a push request and I'll merge it.